# is anyone knows how to add dropdown input inside modal bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need help to add dropdown input inside modal bootstrap. because when I try to put this below code:

```
<select>
    <option>Categories</option>
</select>
```

inside modal bootstrap. there is nothing to show inside modal-body.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide the modal-body's HTML code, and corresponding CSS?

Comment: here is my code :

Comment: Sorry but can't see your code...

Comment: OK. Please close this question if you plan to ask a different one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try the following

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" property='stylesheet' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert-info">
    The MainDropdown works as expected. A minor side note is that clicking directly on the checkbox keeps the dropdown open, whereas clicking on the "label" portion outside of the checkbox closes the dropdown. In either case, the checkbox is appropriately
    toggled.
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      MainDropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action long words to show content</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <label class="dropdown-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" /> Test</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert-danger">
          The ModalDropdown seems to work for "a" tags. Clicking on the input checkbox directly will have the same behavior as MainDropdown in Chrome 56, but in Firefox 51 the menu will close. Clicking on the "label" portion outside of the checkbox will close the dropdown in either browser without toggling the checkbox state.
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            ModalDropdown
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action long words to show content</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <label class="dropdown-item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" /> Test</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```